# Don't know how to correctly identify crash logged in Firebase Crashlytics with Swift

Tags: swift

I got a fatal error detected by Firebase Crashlytics, but I can't understand exactly what it means.

This is the error:

```
  Crashed: NSOperationQueue 0x13b9b5560 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED)
0  CDA                            0x789a8 closure #1 in closure #1 in UploadGedaveWebViewController.apagarImagensNoGedaveWeb(_:_:) + 4296493480
1  CDA                            0x4d4cc thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable (@guaranteed Data?, @guaranteed NSURLResponse?, @guaranteed Error?) -> () + 4296316108 (<compiler-generated>:4296316108)
2  CFNetwork                      0x25be4 CFNetServiceBrowserSearchForServices + 93664
3  CFNetwork                      0x366f4 _CFHTTPMessageSetResponseProxyURL + 9540
4  Foundation                     0x114410 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
5  Foundation                     0x1e138 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 100
6  Foundation                     0x116698 __NSOPERATION_IS_INVOKING_MAIN__ + 20
7  Foundation                     0x1ddd0 -[NSOperation start] + 732
8  Foundation                     0x117090 __NSOPERATIONQUEUE_IS_STARTING_AN_OPERATION__ + 20
9  Foundation                     0x116b5c __NSOQSchedule_f + 180
10 libdispatch.dylib              0xe7dc _dispatch_block_async_invoke2 + 104
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x5c184 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x4a3c _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x4190 _dispatch_async_redirect_invoke + 600
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x10fa4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 376
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x11770 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 128
16 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xbb48 _pthread_wqthread + 212
17 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xe760 start_wqthread + 8
```

I understand that the error is generate by the function "UploadGedaveWebViewController.apagarImagensNoGedaveWeb", but I don't understand what exactly has caused the crash.

This is the code

```
func apagarImagensNoGedaveWeb(_ parteAnimal: String, _ idGedave: Int) {
    
    let jsonRequestUploadImagemGraficaParaApagar: [String : Any] = JsonHelper.createJsonMarcaResenhaParaDeletar(parteAnimal, idGedave )
    
    let json: [String: Any] = jsonRequestUploadImagemGraficaParaApagar
    guard let jsonData: Data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json) else {
        return
    }
    
    let requestImagemGrafica: URLRequest = EndpointController.createRequestForEndpoint(Constantes.Endpoint.upload_marca, jsonData, "post")
    
    let urlSession = URLSessionHelper.getUrlSessionByUrlAddress()
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    
        let taskNotSynced = urlSession.dataTask(with: requestImagemGrafica) { data, response, error in
            let myStr = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        taskNotSynced.resume()
    }
    
}
```

What can be the cause of this problem ?

EDIT 3

```
let taskNotSynced = urlSession.dataTask(with: requestImagemGrafica) { data, response, error in
        printDebug("response set")
        printDebug(response as Any)
        printDebug("error: \(String(describing: error))")
        guard let error = error else {
            printDebug("apagarImamge returns error: \(String(describing: error))")
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            printDebug("apagarImamge returns nil")
            return
        }
        let myStr = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        printDebug("myStr: \(String(describing: myStr))")
    }
    taskNotSynced.resume()
```

The problem is not caused by the curly brace before resume

Comment: The line `let myStr = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)` is a problem. What if `data` comes back as `nil`? You need to better handle optionals and check for errors.

Comment: I think u should not be calling the dataTask inside main thread too

Comment: @HangarRash You are right, I suppose this can be the problem.

Comment: @udi It's fine. The data task is asynchronous and won't block the main thread.

Comment: @fabiobh In your update, you should at least print `error` inside the `guard else` block so you know why it failed.

Comment: @HangarRash Yes, thanks for remember me about error.

Comment: Now your 2nd edit is all wrong. You don't want return if `error` is nil.

Comment: You do not need to keep posting more and more edits. Just fix the one edit. Your 3rd edit is still wrong. The `guard let error = error` code will cause a return if there is no error. Clearly you do not want that. And fix the curly braces in your original code to avoid confusion.

Comment: I understand about the _Edits_. If I remove _return_ I got this error from Xcode. 'guard' body must not fall through, consider using a 'return' or 'throw' to exit the scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're calling taskNotSynced.resume() inside the closure of the dataTask method. This can cause the crash.

Also, you should avoid force unwrapping the data variable, as it might be nil if there was an error or if there's no data returned and the app would crash. Instead, safely unwrap the data using an if let.

```
let taskNotSynced = urlSession.dataTask(with: requestImagemGrafica) { data, response, error in
    if let data {
        let myStr = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    } else {
        print("Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
    }
}
taskNotSynced.resume() // Move this line outside of the closure
```

Comment: There's actually a curly brace missing in the OP's question so it's not 100% clear that the problem is due to `resume` being called in the wrong place versus a simple typo in the question.

Comment: I checked the curly brace before _resume_ function. It's in the correct place.

Comment: @fabiobh why are two let urlSession = URLSessionHelper.getUrlSessionByUrlAddress() in the code ?

Comment: There are only one _let urlSession = URLSessionHelper.getUrlSessionByUrlAddress()_ in the code. I wrong put two lines of the code in my question

Comment: @fabiobh try to remove the app and run it again

Comment: @mgsulaiman It works for me. I didn't see more fatal errors show on Crashlytics.